# Question on ideal generated by polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\langle p(x)\rangle$ denote the ideal generated by the polynomial in $\mathbb Q [x]$. Let $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^3-x^2+x-1$ . Let $I=\langle f(x)\rangle+\langle g(x)\rangle$. Then which of the following is/are true?

(A). $I=\langle x^3+x\rangle$

(B). $I=\langle f(x)g(x)\rangle$

(C). $I=\langle x^2+1\rangle$

(D). $I=\langle x^2-1\rangle$.

I think none of the above is correct.
For (A):
Note that $f(x)\in I$. If $f(x)\in \langle x^3+x\rangle$ then $f(x)=x^3+x(p(x))$ for some $p(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$. Then $f(0)=0$ which is not true.

For (B):
$f(x)\in I$. If $f(x)\in \langle f(x)g(x)\rangle$ then $f(x)=f(x)g(x)p(x)$ which is also not true as degree of $f(x)<$ degree of $f(x)g(x)p(x)$.

For (C):
$f(x)\in I $. If $f(x)\in \langle x^2+1\rangle$ then $f(x)=x^2+1(p(x))$ which is not true as $x^2+1$ does not divide $f(x)$.

For (D):
$g(x) \in I$. If $g(x)\in \langle x^2-1\rangle$ then $g(x)=(x^2-1)(p(x))$. Then $g(-1)=0$ which is not true.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle p(x)\rangle,$ not $<p(x)>.$ I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

C is correct because $x^2+1$ divides $f$ and $g$ and is equal to $(f-g)/2$.

The rest of your solution is OK (modulo some misprints).